# Split audio file but only in pauses

Tags: audio, sox, filesplitting

I've been playting around with sox and using the `trim` command it should be fairly simple to split the whole audio into n parts (with a fixed length per part).

However as I intend to split spoken recordings it might happen that a simple splitting will split in the middle of a word.

Is there a way to prevent that and make sure that parts contain "whole words"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the **sox silence** command on the (archived) [sox webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20231025084509/https://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) for manual and [Sound eXchange](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/) on sourceforge.

```
sox original.wav new.wav silence 1 0.5 2% 1 2.0 2% : newfile : restart
```

## Parameters:

**original.wav** - the audio file to be spliced.

**new.wav** - will be the name of the new audio files with numbers appended to each slice (new1.wav, new2.wav, new3.wav...).

**silence** - name of the effect.

**1 0.5 2%** - above_periods, duration, threshold.

**1 2.0 2%** - below_periods, duration, threshold.